# Ruby Errors in console

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Every time I try to do anything related to ruby (`gem list`, `gem uninstall` etc.) I see the following error in my console:

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/Mandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-   p451@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64- darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
 Referenced from: /Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle
 Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
 in /Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/Mandy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.4/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _SSLv2_client_method
Referenced from: /Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle
Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
in /Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle - /Users/Mandy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
```

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this error message?

Comment: Probably you don't have install OpenSSL with rvm

Comment: Ok, so what should I do? `gem install OpenSSL`? I'm not super familiar with anything to do with Ruby - I just use it for some Front-End dependencies....

Comment: I think you can use the solution of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511943/troubles-with-rvm-and-openssl)