# RVM issue with macOS Sierra while installing Ruby 2.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, ruby-2.2

I'm running OSX (10.12.3) and I have Ruby installed (2.2.2) which is working fine. I'm trying to upgrade to 2.2.6 using RVM. Install seems to go fine.

```
  - rvm install 2.2.6
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.2.6.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /location/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.6 - #downloading ruby-2.2.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.6 - #extracting ruby-2.2.6 to /location/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.6....
ruby-2.2.6 - #configuring..........................................................
ruby-2.2.6 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.6 - #compiling...........................................................
ruby-2.2.6 - #installing..........
ruby-2.2.6 - #making binaries executable..
ruby-2.2.6 - #downloading rubygems-2.6.10
ruby-2.2.6 - #extracting rubygems-2.6.10.....
ruby-2.2.6 - #removing old rubygems.........
$LANG was empty, setting up LANG=en_US, if it fails again try setting LANG to something sane and try again.
ruby-2.2.6 - #installing rubygems-2.6.10.....................
ruby-2.2.6 - #gemset created /location/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6@global
ruby-2.2.6 - #importing gemset /location/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems................................................
ruby-2.2.6 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.2.6 - #gemset created /location/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6
ruby-2.2.6 - #importing gemsetfile /location/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.2.6 - #generating default wrappers........
ruby-2.2.6 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-2.2.6 - #complete
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
```

But when I try following commands, I'll get some errors.

```
  - bundle
-bash: bundle: command not found
  - gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

So while installation seems to go fine, it can't require openssl when trying to install any gem. What might be the issue here and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried purging whole RVM and a clean reinstall, which didn't help. Using the answer by phq from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511943/troubles-with-rvm-and-openssl) I managed to get it working.

```
rvm remove 2.2.6   
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 2.2.6 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
gem install bundler
bundle
```

It's probably not the best solution as it manually loads openssl, but it seems to currently be the only solution that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you still don't have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, you should go ahead and give it a try. As they say, "Homebrew installs the stuff you need that Apple didn’t," which in your case is openssl.

1. Install Homebrew: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install openssl: `brew install openssl`
3. Try installing bundler again: `gem install bundler`

To avoid problems in the future, I suggest you take a look at [RVM Autolibs](https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs). It automatically installs any dependency you need using Homebrew or other manager. If you don't wanna read the documentation, just run: `rvm autolibs enable && rvm autolibs packages && rvm autolibs homebrew` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm using Homebrew and had OpenSSL installed at the time. Also, I had autolibs enabled (by default), and there seemed to be some issue which caused that it didn't configure autossl properly (as can be seen from my answer).