# How to "recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support" using RVM?

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm, bundler

After installing Ruby 2.3.8 via RVM I get the following error when running `bundle`:

> You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile

How do I recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support?

Comment: Did you try to recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support as the error message suggests?

Comment: Yes, i tried multiple solutions, even spend a day to get out of this. But after spending so much time i found only following answer was working as solution for my case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you answered your own question.

Answer (score 4):

My Solution for this:

Just run

1: brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/8c9b113bc6812dc74c598c8f860017e42fba8d78/Formula/openssl.rb

2: rvm **install** 2.3 --with-openssl-lib=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-openssl-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

(if rvm is already installed, use **reinstall** instead of install.)

Comment: This might work as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236670/477037

Answer (score 1):

## For rvm on MacOS Mojave

In my case, the installer fails because it is using obsolete parts in the new version of openssl. This has worked for me:

1. Go to the "homebrew-core" folder and get back the old openssl gem(1.0.2t)

   ```
   cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
   git show 8b9d6d688f483a0f33fcfc93d433de501b9c3513:Formula/openssl.rb >> Formula/openssl\@1.0.2t.rb
   ```
2. Enter the file and rename the class "Openssl" to "OpensslAT102t"

   ```
   brew edit Formula/openssl\@1.0.2t.rb
   ```
3. Install it with brew

   ```
   brew install openssl@1.0.2t
   ```
4. Once installed, force rvm to use the installed version of ssl

   ```
   # Install 2.3.8
   rvm install 2.3.8 --disable-binary --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.0.2t`
   # Or reinstall
   rvm reinstall 2.3.8 --disable-binary --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.0.2t`
   ```