# When running rvm install ruby-2.2 an error occurs of make.log posting tail of make.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

I am trying to install ruby-2.2 via rvm as required by minitest in my gemfile.lock but I am experiencing an error as shown in the tail of make.log of ruby-2.2 below.

Tail of make.log:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
compiling compar.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling enum.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
encoding.c:825:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_str_change_terminator_length' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_str_change_terminator_length(obj, oldtermlen, termlen);
        ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [encoding.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

When I try to install it via rbenv it says:

```
dgram_write in libcrypto.a(bss_dgram.o)
      _RAND_query_egd_bytes in libcrypto.a(rand_egd.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [link_a.darwin] Error 1
make[3]: *** [do_darwin-shared] Error 2
make[2]: *** [libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [shared] Error 2
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

Comment: To resolve the above, I'd start by running `brew upgrade openssl`. If that doesn't fix it, you may need to pass a `--with-openssl-dir` parameter [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236670/1954610).

Comment: I would also strongly advise using `rvm` **OR** `rbenv`, but **not both**.

Comment: Thanks @TomLord it worked but also required me to do  `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install`

Comment: Yes I will use rvm and not both

Answer (score 0):

Do upgrade openssl using:

```
brew upgrade openssl
```

but it also required me to remove xcode commandlinetools and then reinstall them

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```