# Cannot install old ruby version

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvmrc

**I am unable to install ruby 2.4.2**

My setup must allow me to use `nvm` and `rvm`, and I need to use ruby versions `2.7.2` and `2.4.2`. I suspect you may find multiple problems with my `openssl` and `rvm` setup. Also, I am not sure which version of `openssl` is appropriate for me. I am using `macOS Monterey` Version `12.3.1`.

When I do:

> ```
>   rvm install 2.4.2
> ```

I see this error in my ..._ruby-2.4.2/configure.log

> configure: error: something wrong with
> LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"

The following info may relate to the problem:

> openssl version # LibreSSL 2.8.3

~/.zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
HIST_STAMPS="dd/mm/yyyy"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export RUBY_CFLAGS="-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC"
```

~/.bashrc

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

~/.bash_profile

```
PATH="~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/sqlite3:$PATH"
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

source ~/.bashrc

# Disabled the next line
# source ~/.profile

alias start_puma="bundle exec puma -p 3000 -S ~/puma -C config/puma.rb"

parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/[\1]/p'
}
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
export PROMPT='%F{grey}%n%f %F{cyan}%~%f %F{green}$(parse_git_branch)%f %F{normal}$%f '

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: I have gone in circles uninstalling and reinstalling anything relating to rvm and openssl, but every time I run into this error:

    `checking whether LDFLAGS is valid... no 
    configure: error: something wrong with LDFLAGS="-    L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"`

Comment: Info [in this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15511943/249353) might help you? I've had this problem as well, although not on a mac. Cannot remember how/if I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I identified two problems:

1. My LDFLAGS had the wrong path in ~/.zshrc
2. I did not understand why `openssl version` produced `LibreSSL 2.8.3`

I found the correct path to the `LDFLAGS` within the errors produced by `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`. The errors included:

> For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

The response to `openssl version` is still `LibreSSL 2.8.3` and I assume this is correct.

I have also learned that `~/.zshrc` must include `source ~/.bash_profile`, and that `~/.bash_profile` must include `source ~/.bashrc`.

I am now able to open a new shell window and see the correct results for `rvm list` (listing the available ruby versions) and `nvm list` (listing the available node versions).

I am also able to install the ruby versions I want.